# Evaluate $\sum \ln \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I tried to calculate the sum of the following series without success, any clue would be helpful!
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right) $$

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far so that we can help you continue from there?

Comment: A sum of log is the log of product, and the product is rather easy to compute, just try a few terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\prod_{n=2}^{2N}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)=\prod_{m=1}^{N}\left(1+\frac{1}{2m}\right)\prod_{m=1}^{N-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2m+1}\right)=\frac{2N+1}{2N}=1+\frac{1}{2N}. $$

Comment: And funnily, for odd products, you get exactly $1$, which is easily seen by multiplying your formula by $1-1/(2N+1)=2N/(2N+1)$.